# Calling Classic ASP from C# ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I need to call a VBscript function on a classic asp page from some server-side c#.net code - does anyone know of a clean way to do this?  Rewriting the function in .net is not an option.

I'll explain a bit more about the problem...

The client side function in question is an MD5 implementation written in VBScript & used to hash passwords.  I'm redeloping the site in .Net, and want to move the password encryption across to SHA, in order to do this I need to catch the users on the first logon with the old mechanism (legacy MD5 implementation), hash their passwords using SHA & store the new hashes for future use.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to authenticate the users on the new .Net site using the old MD5 implementation.

I've tried the suggestions posted, but for some strange reason when I call the function from a 'foo.asp' page (which only serves to call the function) it gives me different results to the legacy site!

Going a bit crazy with this one - perhaps it's an encoding thing?

I've also tried to convert the Legacy MD5 algorithm to .Net, but to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the legacy script:

```
<%
' Derived from the RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm,
' as set out in the memo RFC1321.

Private Const BITS_TO_A_BYTE = 8
Private Const BYTES_TO_A_WORD = 4
Private Const BITS_TO_A_WORD = 32

Private m_lOnBits(30)
Private m_l2Power(30)

m_lOnBits(0) = CLng(1)
m_lOnBits(1) = CLng(3)
m_lOnBits(2) = CLng(7)
m_lOnBits(3) = CLng(15)
m_lOnBits(4) = CLng(31)
m_lOnBits(5) = CLng(63)
m_lOnBits(6) = CLng(127)
m_lOnBits(7) = CLng(255)
m_lOnBits(8) = CLng(511)
m_lOnBits(9) = CLng(1023)
m_lOnBits(10) = CLng(2047)
m_lOnBits(11) = CLng(4095)
m_lOnBits(12) = CLng(8191)
m_lOnBits(13) = CLng(16383)
m_lOnBits(14) = CLng(32767)
m_lOnBits(15) = CLng(65535)
m_lOnBits(16) = CLng(131071)
m_lOnBits(17) = CLng(262143)
m_lOnBits(18) = CLng(524287)
m_lOnBits(19) = CLng(1048575)
m_lOnBits(20) = CLng(2097151)
m_lOnBits(21) = CLng(4194303)
m_lOnBits(22) = CLng(8388607)
m_lOnBits(23) = CLng(16777215)
m_lOnBits(24) = CLng(33554431)
m_lOnBits(25) = CLng(67108863)
m_lOnBits(26) = CLng(134217727)
m_lOnBits(27) = CLng(268435455)
m_lOnBits(28) = CLng(536870911)
m_lOnBits(29) = CLng(1073741823)
m_lOnBits(30) = CLng(2147483647)

m_l2Power(0) = CLng(1)
m_l2Power(1) = CLng(2)
m_l2Power(2) = CLng(4)
m_l2Power(3) = CLng(8)
m_l2Power(4) = CLng(16)
m_l2Power(5) = CLng(32)
m_l2Power(6) = CLng(64)
m_l2Power(7) = CLng(128)
m_l2Power(8) = CLng(256)
m_l2Power(9) = CLng(512)
m_l2Power(10) = CLng(1024)
m_l2Power(11) = CLng(2048)
m_l2Power(12) = CLng(4096)
m_l2Power(13) = CLng(8192)
m_l2Power(14) = CLng(16384)
m_l2Power(15) = CLng(32768)
m_l2Power(16) = CLng(65536)
m_l2Power(17) = CLng(131072)
m_l2Power(18) = CLng(262144)
m_l2Power(19) = CLng(524288)
m_l2Power(20) = CLng(1048576)
m_l2Power(21) = CLng(2097152)
m_l2Power(22) = CLng(4194304)
m_l2Power(23) = CLng(8388608)
m_l2Power(24) = CLng(16777216)
m_l2Power(25) = CLng(33554432)
m_l2Power(26) = CLng(67108864)
m_l2Power(27) = CLng(134217728)
m_l2Power(28) = CLng(268435456)
m_l2Power(29) = CLng(536870912)
m_l2Power(30) = CLng(1073741824)

Private Function LShift(lValue, iShiftBits)
    If iShiftBits = 0 Then
        LShift = lValue
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits = 31 Then
        If lValue And 1 Then
            LShift = &H80000000
        Else
            LShift = 0
        End If
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits < 0 Or iShiftBits > 31 Then
        Err.Raise 6
    End If

    If (lValue And m_l2Power(31 - iShiftBits)) Then
        LShift = ((lValue And m_lOnBits(31 - (iShiftBits + 1))) * m_l2Power(iShiftBits)) Or &H80000000
    Else
        LShift = ((lValue And m_lOnBits(31 - iShiftBits)) * m_l2Power(iShiftBits))
    End If
End Function

Private Function RShift(lValue, iShiftBits)
    If iShiftBits = 0 Then
        RShift = lValue
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits = 31 Then
        If lValue And &H80000000 Then
            RShift = 1
        Else
            RShift = 0
        End If
        Exit Function
    ElseIf iShiftBits < 0 Or iShiftBits > 31 Then
        Err.Raise 6
    End If

    RShift = (lValue And &H7FFFFFFE) \ m_l2Power(iShiftBits)

    If (lValue And &H80000000) Then
        RShift = (RShift Or (&H40000000 \ m_l2Power(iShiftBits - 1)))
    End If
End Function

Private Function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits)
    RotateLeft = LShift(lValue, iShiftBits) Or RShift(lValue, (32 - iShiftBits))
End Function

Private Function AddUnsigned(lX, lY)
    Dim lX4
    Dim lY4
    Dim lX8
    Dim lY8
    Dim lResult

    lX8 = lX And &H80000000
    lY8 = lY And &H80000000
    lX4 = lX And &H40000000
    lY4 = lY And &H40000000

    lResult = (lX And &H3FFFFFFF) + (lY And &H3FFFFFFF)

    If lX4 And lY4 Then
        lResult = lResult Xor &H80000000 Xor lX8 Xor lY8
    ElseIf lX4 Or lY4 Then
        If lResult And &H40000000 Then
            lResult = lResult Xor &HC0000000 Xor lX8 Xor lY8
        Else
            lResult = lResult Xor &H40000000 Xor lX8 Xor lY8
        End If
    Else
        lResult = lResult Xor lX8 Xor lY8
    End If

    AddUnsigned = lResult
End Function

Private Function F(x, y, z)
    F = (x And y) Or ((Not x) And z)
End Function

Private Function G(x, y, z)
    G = (x And z) Or (y And (Not z))
End Function

Private Function H(x, y, z)
    H = (x Xor y Xor z)
End Function

Private Function I(x, y, z)
    I = (y Xor (x Or (Not z)))
End Function

Private Sub FF(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac))
    a = RotateLeft(a, s)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, b)
End Sub

Private Sub GG(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac))
    a = RotateLeft(a, s)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, b)
End Sub

Private Sub HH(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac))
    a = RotateLeft(a, s)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, b)
End Sub

Private Sub II(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac))
    a = RotateLeft(a, s)
    a = AddUnsigned(a, b)
End Sub

Private Function ConvertToWordArray(sMessage)
    Dim lMessageLength
    Dim lNumberOfWords
    Dim lWordArray()
    Dim lBytePosition
    Dim lByteCount
    Dim lWordCount

    Const MODULUS_BITS = 512
    Const CONGRUENT_BITS = 448

    lMessageLength = Len(sMessage)

    lNumberOfWords = (((lMessageLength + ((MODULUS_BITS - CONGRUENT_BITS) \ BITS_TO_A_BYTE)) \  (MODULUS_BITS \ BITS_TO_A_BYTE)) + 1) * (MODULUS_BITS \ BITS_TO_A_WORD)
ReDim lWordArray(lNumberOfWords - 1)

lBytePosition = 0
lByteCount = 0
Do Until lByteCount >= lMessageLength
    lWordCount = lByteCount \ BYTES_TO_A_WORD
    lBytePosition = (lByteCount Mod BYTES_TO_A_WORD) * BITS_TO_A_BYTE
    lWordArray(lWordCount) = lWordArray(lWordCount) Or LShift(Asc(Mid(sMessage, lByteCount + 1, 1)), lBytePosition)
    lByteCount = lByteCount + 1
Loop

lWordCount = lByteCount \ BYTES_TO_A_WORD
lBytePosition = (lByteCount Mod BYTES_TO_A_WORD) * BITS_TO_A_BYTE

lWordArray(lWordCount) = lWordArray(lWordCount) Or LShift(&H80, lBytePosition)

lWordArray(lNumberOfWords - 2) = LShift(lMessageLength, 3)
lWordArray(lNumberOfWords - 1) = RShift(lMessageLength, 29)

ConvertToWordArray = lWordArray
End Function

Private Function WordToHex(lValue)
Dim lByte
Dim lCount

For lCount = 0 To 3
    lByte = RShift(lValue, lCount * BITS_TO_A_BYTE) And m_lOnBits(BITS_TO_A_BYTE - 1)
    WordToHex = WordToHex & Right("0" & Hex(lByte), 2)
Next
End Function

Public Function MD5(sMessage)
Dim x
Dim k
Dim AA
Dim BB
Dim CC
Dim DD
Dim a
Dim b
Dim c
Dim d

Const S11 = 7
Const S12 = 12
Const S13 = 17
Const S14 = 22
Const S21 = 5
Const S22 = 9
Const S23 = 14
Const S24 = 20
Const S31 = 4
Const S32 = 11
Const S33 = 16
Const S34 = 23
Const S41 = 6
Const S42 = 10
Const S43 = 15
Const S44 = 21

x = ConvertToWordArray(sMessage)

a = &H67452301
b = &HEFCDAB89
c = &H98BADCFE
d = &H10325476

For k = 0 To UBound(x) Step 16
    AA = a
    BB = b
    CC = c
    DD = d

    FF a, b, c, d, x(k + 0), S11, &HD76AA478
    FF d, a, b, c, x(k + 1), S12, &HE8C7B756
    FF c, d, a, b, x(k + 2), S13, &H242070DB
    FF b, c, d, a, x(k + 3), S14, &HC1BDCEEE
    FF a, b, c, d, x(k + 4), S11, &HF57C0FAF
    FF d, a, b, c, x(k + 5), S12, &H4787C62A
    FF c, d, a, b, x(k + 6), S13, &HA8304613
    FF b, c, d, a, x(k + 7), S14, &HFD469501
    FF a, b, c, d, x(k + 8), S11, &H698098D8
    FF d, a, b, c, x(k + 9), S12, &H8B44F7AF
    FF c, d, a, b, x(k + 10), S13, &HFFFF5BB1
    FF b, c, d, a, x(k + 11), S14, &H895CD7BE
    FF a, b, c, d, x(k + 12), S11, &H6B901122
    FF d, a, b, c, x(k + 13), S12, &HFD987193
    FF c, d, a, b, x(k + 14), S13, &HA679438E
    FF b, c, d, a, x(k + 15), S14, &H49B40821

    GG a, b, c, d, x(k + 1), S21, &HF61E2562
    GG d, a, b, c, x(k + 6), S22, &HC040B340
    GG c, d, a, b, x(k + 11), S23, &H265E5A51
    GG b, c, d, a, x(k + 0), S24, &HE9B6C7AA
    GG a, b, c, d, x(k + 5), S21, &HD62F105D
    GG d, a, b, c, x(k + 10), S22, &H2441453
    GG c, d, a, b, x(k + 15), S23, &HD8A1E681
    GG b, c, d, a, x(k + 4), S24, &HE7D3FBC8
    GG a, b, c, d, x(k + 9), S21, &H21E1CDE6
    GG d, a, b, c, x(k + 14), S22, &HC33707D6
    GG c, d, a, b, x(k + 3), S23, &HF4D50D87
    GG b, c, d, a, x(k + 8), S24, &H455A14ED
    GG a, b, c, d, x(k + 13), S21, &HA9E3E905
    GG d, a, b, c, x(k + 2), S22, &HFCEFA3F8
    GG c, d, a, b, x(k + 7), S23, &H676F02D9
    GG b, c, d, a, x(k + 12), S24, &H8D2A4C8A

    HH a, b, c, d, x(k + 5), S31, &HFFFA3942
    HH d, a, b, c, x(k + 8), S32, &H8771F681
    HH c, d, a, b, x(k + 11), S33, &H6D9D6122
    HH b, c, d, a, x(k + 14), S34, &HFDE5380C
    HH a, b, c, d, x(k + 1), S31, &HA4BEEA44
    HH d, a, b, c, x(k + 4), S32, &H4BDECFA9
    HH c, d, a, b, x(k + 7), S33, &HF6BB4B60
    HH b, c, d, a, x(k + 10), S34, &HBEBFBC70
    HH a, b, c, d, x(k + 13), S31, &H289B7EC6
    HH d, a, b, c, x(k + 0), S32, &HEAA127FA
    HH c, d, a, b, x(k + 3), S33, &HD4EF3085
    HH b, c, d, a, x(k + 6), S34, &H4881D05
    HH a, b, c, d, x(k + 9), S31, &HD9D4D039
    HH d, a, b, c, x(k + 12), S32, &HE6DB99E5
    HH c, d, a, b, x(k + 15), S33, &H1FA27CF8
    HH b, c, d, a, x(k + 2), S34, &HC4AC5665

    II a, b, c, d, x(k + 0), S41, &HF4292244
    II d, a, b, c, x(k + 7), S42, &H432AFF97
    II c, d, a, b, x(k + 14), S43, &HAB9423A7
    II b, c, d, a, x(k + 5), S44, &HFC93A039
    II a, b, c, d, x(k + 12), S41, &H655B59C3
    II d, a, b, c, x(k + 3), S42, &H8F0CCC92
    II c, d, a, b, x(k + 10), S43, &HFFEFF47D
    II b, c, d, a, x(k + 1), S44, &H85845DD1
    II a, b, c, d, x(k + 8), S41, &H6FA87E4F
    II d, a, b, c, x(k + 15), S42, &HFE2CE6E0
    II c, d, a, b, x(k + 6), S43, &HA3014314
    II b, c, d, a, x(k + 13), S44, &H4E0811A1
    II a, b, c, d, x(k + 4), S41, &HF7537E82
    II d, a, b, c, x(k + 11), S42, &HBD3AF235
    II c, d, a, b, x(k + 2), S43, &H2AD7D2BB
    II b, c, d, a, x(k + 9), S44, &HEB86D391

    a = AddUnsigned(a, AA)
    b = AddUnsigned(b, BB)
    c = AddUnsigned(c, CC)
    d = AddUnsigned(d, DD)
Next

MD5 = LCase(WordToHex(a) & WordToHex(b) & WordToHex(c) & WordToHex(d))
End Function
%>
```

Comment: What are the details as to why you can't use .NET's own `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: Because it's a legacy system using the encryption algorithm above - if I use .Net own provider it will not create the same hashes, so my 10,000+ userbase will not be able to log in to the new system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your VBScript function is accessible via HTTP. If it's not, go expose it by making a new page like `foo.asp` where all it does is call into `MyFunction()`.

If this is the case, then your code-behind can use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y1032) class to call:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
Stream data = client.OpenRead ("http://server/foo.asp?bar=baz");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
data.Close ();
reader.Close ();
```

Comment: This has now been resolved - I suspect some error on my part in testing for the initial failure, but calling the classic asp page via a webclient DID work - Thanks I'll mark your answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly.

One way will be to change the classic ASP to something like this:

```
If Request("execute_func")="true" Then
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Write(MyFunc())
    Response.End()
End If
```

Then consume the page using HttpWebRequest or something similar (WebClient might be option as well) and passing the flag on the URL e.g:

```
string sURL = "http://www.yoursite.com/mypage.asp?execute_func=true;
```

Then read the response and this is the function return value.